How to move bones from one armature to another?
Situation:
I have a bending armature on a piece of sheet metal, named left bend (Red circle in screenshot), in object mode I duplicated and mirrored the armature and renamed the duplicate armature right bend (Green circle in screenshot). I'm still learning the basics, but after doing the armature duplicating and mirror, I realized that I can't make a mesh parented to multiple armatures (or can/should you?), but that made me think what I need to do was go into EDIT mode and just duplicate and mirror the specific bone chain. And then actually the armature should just be renamed to SHEET METAL RIG since it would essentially be one full rig with multiple bone chains for each part that should bend and not actually have separate armatures.
Question:
Since I already renamed all my bones for the right side like right.bend.001, right.bend.002, etc, so how could I just move all the bones from the right bend armature into the original armature named left bend (which I will actually rename the armature to SHEET METAL RIG)? In the end I should then have a bone chain for the left and bone chain for the right all within the armature SHEET METAL RIG, right?
Thanks for you help on this :)


